# Overloading by private method with converted parameter

Tags: c++

With the following code, I get: `error: ‘void B::add(int)’ is private`. I'm just surprised but also disappointed to get this... I know that `add(int)` method is private, but why the compiler can't continue to look for other solutions, i.e. construct an `A` object, as the constructor is `A(int)` ?

Is this behavior defined by the C++ standard ?

Is there a solution to this problem, or I must rename my private method / apply pimpl idiom ?

Thanks.

```
struct A
{
  A(int) {}
};


struct B
{
  void add(const A&) { } 

private:
  void add(int) { } 
};

int main()
{
  B b;
  b.add(5);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is defined in the standard. Overload resolution comes before access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `void add(int)` is the best match for `b.add(5)`.

You can get around the problem by using `b.add(A(5));`.